# webpack code splitting in imported library

Tags: webpack

I have a webapp, A, which I'm building with webpack 2.  I also have a library, L, which I'm also building with webpack 2; A imports L to do its job.  So far so good.

I run into trouble when attempting to use `require.ensure()` in my library to code-split out a pretty large dependency that's only used in certain code paths.  Webpack appears to build the library correctly, and I see an extra chunk emitted to my library's output directory, but when I run webpack-dev-server to serve up my app I get browser console errors complaining that chunk loading failed:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/0.index.js 404
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
  at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete
```

`0.index.js` is indeed the library chunk containing my big fat dependency.  setting `output.chunkFilename` in my library's webpack config did change the URL of the HTTP request made to webpack-dev-server, but still resulted in a 404:

```
GET http://localhost:8081/library-chunk-0.js
```

I'm using this webpack config for my library:

```
{
  entry: './src/index.js',

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }]
  },

  output: {
    chunkFilename: 'library-chunk-[name].js',
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'my-library',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  }
}
```

There are no chunks of my library in my webapp's output directory.  How do I get all chunks of my library to be made available in my webapp's output directory, so that they can be served up by webpack-dev-server (and therefore be present when I distribute the webapp)?

Answer (score 1):

`webpack-dev-server`, [doesn't store bundle files on the disk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/62), but serves them on the fly. So you won't be able to find them in your dist directory, and that's not the problem.

I noticed that you specify [`output.library` and `output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) on your config object.

Since you are building an application and those are special configurations for authoring libraries, you probably don't need them. Try to remove them, since they fit a different scenario than async chunks and might conflict.